# Where to put entity model classes in case of using a dataservice layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

If my solution has both a "dataservice" project and a "business logic" project, where do the entity models, which represent database tables, belong?

At first i thought putting them in the dataservice layer, but then i would need duplicate models in the business logic layer, if i wanted to provide reusable logic dealing with or being dependant of database data.

Putting models in the business logic project, would force the dataservice layer to be dependant on the core project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate "Domain" project that contains your Domain Entities.

Important note:  Your Entities may not be the same thing as your datatables.

Your "DataService" project should know how to *map* from Domain Entities to datatables.